# Magento 2 : Transaction mail Logo And Footer Default Links

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, logo, footer-links

- I have question about **transaction mail** why mail **logo** can not set ?
  I have already set `Content > Configuration > transnational`
  mail
- and links like **About Us and Customer Service in footer in transnational mail** , How can i **Change This Links href** ? and where it is came From ?[image]

Comment: let me know do u use theme?

Comment: let me know your theme name please?

Comment: Sir , i am used **Magento Luma theme** , not used any Custom Theme.

Comment: please check the path /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

Comment: thank you sir, i dont want to change magento core files , so how can i **override** this footer.html , where the  **xml file** for footer.html ?

Comment: Ok then u should create custom theme using the developer documentation (or) following stack user's  QA's for your reference https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-theme-create-sample-custome-theme/

Comment: Sir  NAGARAJU KASA , i want to know that Path of which template file can be used for a header part of transaction mail for Magento Luma theme ?

Comment: please check this vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html

Comment: sir, i get logo url in mail like `src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/HYObVUcNwF8__rDBAKGZTbPXK1i9nWErs94hM784OScNJrMYd4Pes2nhUbgnD-u2QlNZy5NPg5lLHebOAyAm_g18K7_ztqaBWqj9frmDzhnb3XwQBMY4DboTeVD5F-yc=s0-d-e1-ft#http://192.168.2.14/abc/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/logo_old.png"` but i want only  **http://192.168.2.14/abc/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/logo_old.png"** from this logo url for correct logo icon !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check the path

vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Email/email/foot‌​er.html

vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html

Answer (score 1):

In `vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Email/Logo` find this constant:

```
const UPLOAD_DIR = 'email/logo';
```

and changed it to:

```
const UPLOAD_DIR = 'logo';
```

also in `vendor/magento/module-email/etc/di.xml`, replace `email/logo` with just `logo`:

```
<item name="value" xsi:type="string">email/logo</item>
```

to:

```
<item name="value" xsi:type="string">logo</item>
```

And then upload email logo again and check email.

Reference: [Magento 2: Fails to upload a transactional email logo from admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128237/magento-2-fails-to-upload-a-transactional-email-logo-from-admin)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below paths:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Email/email/header.html
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Email/email/footer.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in magento 2.1.

Follow these steps to fix it:

1. create di.xml into you custom module
2. add `<preference for="Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Backend\Logo" type="Vendor\YouModuleName\Model\Design\Backend\Logo"/>`
3. create the file Vendor\YouModuleName\Model\Design\Backend\Logo.php
4. replace the const `UPLOAD_DIR = 'logo';` with const `UPLOAD_DIR = 'email/logo';`
5. Test!

There is also an easiest work around without modifying code:

1. create the directory pub/media/email/logo/default
2. copy the logo to the directory manually.
3. Then via the correct procedure Content > Design > Configuration > Edit > Transnational emails

Now upload the same logo you you manually added to the newly created directory.

To change the footer link, edit footer.html in your theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/footer.html
```

Comment: Mam , i am used **Magento Luma theme** , not used any Custom Theme.

Comment: You can override the file in your custom theme. You can create your custom theme by following this doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.1.x, there is this problem.

**Problem**

> In admin,
>
> - you go to `Content > Design > Configuration > Edit your current theme`
> - then, you go to `Transactional Emails` section
> - and upload your email logo image there
> - then, click on `save configuration` or `save and continue` button
> - and when you go back to editing your current theme, you don't see your uploaded image in the `Transactional Emails` section

**Cause**

> The image is actually intended to be saved in the following location:
>
> `YOUR_MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/media/email/logo/stores/YOUR_STORE_ID/YOUR_IMAGE.png`
>
> (supposing your image name to be `YOUR_IMAGE.png`)
>
> However, due to a bug in Magento 2.1.x, the image is saved in
>   location:
>
> `YOUR_MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/media/logo/stores/YOUR_STORE_ID/YOUR_IMAGE.png`

**Solution**

> Not much flexible but a simple solution will be to copy the image
>
> from `pub/media/logo/stores/your_store_id/your_image.png`
>
> to `pub/media/email/logo/stores/your_store_id/your_image.png`

---

> After that, you go to `Content > Design > Configuration > Edit your current theme`
>
> then, you go to `Transactional Emails` section
>
> and upload your email logo image there
>
> then, click on `save configuration` or `save and continue` button