# Magento 2.1.6 Unable to Set Transaction Email Logo

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

Logo was uploaded to Theme Settings -> Transactional Email. I've done the following:

1. Clear all cache.
2. Clear static content.
3. Test transactional email then
       repeat above process.

The default Magento logo persists. I'm running developer mode, is there something I missed?

Comment: Hey did you look at this thread before ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128237/magento-2-fails-to-upload-a-transactional-email-logo-from-admin

Comment: @ethan wan this logo issue has been fixed in 2.1.7 just check it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is happening and I hope someone can give a proper explanation to this:

After I upload my logo, I notice the logo url is:
`/media/email/logo/websites/1/my-email-logo.jpg` (this gives 404 as the path is not correct)

So after a search, the correct email logo path is:
`/media/logo/websites/1/my-email-logo.jpg` (notice without `/email`, and this is where email logo is stored after uploaded via admin.)

I tried to pin point the issue with no luck, so took a short cut I created a new path: /media/email/logo/websites/1/ and copied my email logo there.

As I expected, the correct logo now shows in my inbox. I'm sure someone with the right knowledge knows what's going on, so please give a comment of your thoughts or maybe this just a another bug.

PS: My theme doesn't alter any transactional email templates.